Change the horizantal axis crosses in a python bar chart
I apologize if this is an easy and simple question that has already been answered. I have some data I am trying to chart as a clustered bar graph using a pandas dataframe in python and so far it has worked without issue. The only problem I am having is that I want the x-axis to cross at value 1 instead of value 0 as is default. Essentially I am doing it so values less than 1 will be pointing down and values greater will be going upwards. I have not been able to find an easy way to do so and was wondering if anyone knew of the command to change the crossing point of the x axis.
Adding in a picture from excel to show how I would want it since I am not sure I am explaining well

Please [edit] your question to include a [mre].

By importing pyplot, it will allow you to change the axis.
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [1, 2, 3, 4],
    'B': [2, 3, 4, 5]
})

ax = df.plot(kind='bar')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position(('data', 1))

plt.show()

To get more like your screenshot, you can set bottom=1 for all bars to start at 1 and extend upwards for >1 and downwards for <1.
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Group 1': [-3, -4, -5, -6],
    'Group 2': [-1, 3, 4, 5]
}).T

ax = df.plot(kind='bar', bottom=1)
ax.axhline(1)

plt.show()


Unfortunately, while that did shift the axis it did not change the data visualization in the way I wished. I added a picture of how I would like it to look by plotting it in excel.
